# Python - making my code more economic

Tags: python

I need some help on making this code more economical - I am sure that, there are a lot of lines I can cut down on.

The code is about a quiz that will ask 10 questions and your score will be outputted at the end.

```
import random
studentname=input("what is your name?:")
score=0
trueanswer=0

def question():
    global operation
    global number1
    global number2
    global studentanswer
    global score
    number1=random.randrange(1,10)
    number2=random.randrange(1,10)
    operation=random.choice(["*","-","+"])
    print("what is", number1,operation,number2,"?:")
    studentanswer=int(input("insert answer:"))

def checking():
    global score
    if operation == "*":
        trueanswer = number1*number2
        if studentanswer == trueanswer:
            print("correct")
            score=score+1
        else:
            print("incorrect")
            score=score
    elif operation == "-":
        trueanswer = number1-number2
        if studentanswer == trueanswer:
            print("correct")
            score=score+1
        else:
            print("incorrect")
            score=score
    elif operation == "+":
        trueanswer = number1+number2
        if studentanswer == trueanswer:
            print("correct")
            score = score+1
        else:
           print("incorrect")
           score=score

def main():
    for i in range (10):
        question()
        checking()
    print("your score is", score)

main()
```

Comment: First eliminate obvious code duplication, then https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html

Comment: Working code should be posed on codereview.stackexchange.com for such suggestions.

Answer (score -3):

You can reduce the entire checking function to this:

```
def checking():
    trueanswer = eval(str(number1)+operation+str(number2))
    if studentanswer == trueanswer:
        print("correct")
        score=score+1
    else:
        print("incorrect")
        score=score
```

Comment: Cutting down on useless lines may be worth the effort, it's definitely not worth introducing horrid tricks. Especially, encouraging the use of `eval` is never a good thing.
As a sidenote, when you see a long chain of `if...elif...else`, it is usually a sign that the code would benefit from using some abstraction such as a lightweight [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I wasn't aware of this issue with exec/eval.